# Split column string elements within a row inside a dataframe

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a matrix (1000 x 2830) like this:

```
        9178    3574    3547
160     B_B     B_B      A_A
301     B_B     A_B      A_B
303     B_B     B_B      A_A
311     A_B     A_B      A_A
312     B_B     A_B      A_A
314     B_B     A_B      A_A
```

and I want to obtain the following (duplicating colnames and splitting each element of each column):

```
      9178   9178   3574   3574   3547   3547
160     B      B      B      B      A      A
301     B      B      A      B      A      B
303     B      B      B      B      A      A
311     A      B      A      B      A      A
312     B      B      A      B      A      A
314     B      B      A      B      A      A
```

I tried using `strsplit` but I got error messages because this is a matrix, not a string. Could you please provide some ideas for resolving this?

Comment: None of it looks like a matrix at the moment. Could you try formatting it a little differently?

Comment: Consider using a prefix or suffix on the column names like 9178_1 and 9178_2 to _avoid_ duplicated column names (which makes it much more difficult to select the right columns later)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an option using `dplyr` (for `bind_cols`) and `tidyr` (for `separate_`) together with `lapply` from base R. It assumes that your data is a data.frame (i.e. you might need to convert it to data.frame first):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

lapply(names(df), function(x) separate_(df[x], x, paste0(x,"_",1:2), sep = "_" )) %>% 
  bind_cols
#  X9178_1 X9178_2 X3574_1 X3574_2 X3547_1 X3547_2
#1       B       B       B       B       A       A
#2       B       B       A       B       A       B
#3       B       B       B       B       A       A
#4       A       B       A       B       A       A
#5       B       B       A       B       A       A
#6       B       B       A       B       A       A
```

Comment: Seems to miss out on the rownames though--need a slight modification.

Comment: @July, are you interested in the original row names? Do they carry any information you require?

Comment: Yes, rownames are important but I recovered them from matrix used as input for lapply function. Thanks for your interest

Comment: If you need the row names, you can just add the following to the existing code: `... %>% mutate(row = rownames(df))`

Answer (score 6):

I'm biased, but I would recommend using `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package. Since it appears that you have `rownames` in your input, use `as.data.table(., keep.rownames = TRUE)`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(as.data.table(mydf, keep.rownames = TRUE), names(mydf), "_")
#     rn X9178_1 X9178_2 X3574_1 X3574_2 X3547_1 X3547_2
# 1: 160       B       B       B       B       A       A
# 2: 301       B       B       A       B       A       B
# 3: 303       B       B       B       B       A       A
# 4: 311       A       B       A       B       A       A
# 5: 312       B       B       A       B       A       A
# 6: 314       B       B       A       B       A       A
```

---

Less legible than `cSplit` (but presently likely to be faster) would be to use `stri_split_fixed` from "stringi", like this:

```
library(stringi)
`dimnames<-`(do.call(cbind, 
                     lapply(mydf, stri_split_fixed, "_", simplify = TRUE)), 
             list(rownames(mydf), rep(colnames(mydf), each = 2)))
#     X9178 X9178 X3574 X3574 X3547 X3547
# 160 "B"   "B"   "B"   "B"   "A"   "A"  
# 301 "B"   "B"   "A"   "B"   "A"   "B"  
# 303 "B"   "B"   "B"   "B"   "A"   "A"  
# 311 "A"   "B"   "A"   "B"   "A"   "A"  
# 312 "B"   "B"   "A"   "B"   "A"   "A"  
# 314 "B"   "B"   "A"   "B"   "A"   "A"
```

If speed is of the essence, I would suggest checking out the ["iotools" package](https://github.com/s-u/iotools), particularly the `mstrsplit` function. The approach would be similar to the "stringi" approach:

```
library(iotools)
`dimnames<-`(do.call(cbind, 
                lapply(mydf, mstrsplit, "_", ncol = 2, type = "character")),
             list(rownames(mydf), rep(colnames(mydf), each = 2)))
```

You may need to add an `lapply(mydf, as character)` in there if you forgot to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when converting from a `matrix` to a `data.frame`, but it should still beat even the `stri_split` approach.

Comment: The second solution is remarkably fast (see the benchmark below)

Answer (score 4):

Something you can do, although it seems a bit "twisted" (`yourmat` being your matrix)...:

```
inter<-data.frame(t(sapply(as.vector(yourmat), function(x) {
                                                 strsplit(x, "_")[[1]]
                                             })),
                   row.names=paste0(rep(colnames(yourmat), e=nrow(yourmat)), 1:nrow(yourmat)),
                   stringsAsFactors=F)
res<-do.call("cbind", 
              split(inter, factor(substr(row.names(inter), 1, 4), level = colnames(yourmat))))
res
#       9178.X1 9178.X2 3574.X1 3574.X2 3547.X1 3547.X2
# 91781       B       B       B       B       A       A
# 91782       B       B       A       B       A       B
# 91783       B       B       B       B       A       A
# 91784       A       B       A       B       A       A
# 91785       B       B       A       B       A       A
# 91786       B       B       A       B       A       A
```

**Edit**
If you want the `row.names` of `res`to be the same as in `yourmat`, you can do:

```
row.names(res)<-row.names(yourmat)
```

***NB:*** If `yourmat` is a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix` the `as.vector` function in the first line needs to be changed to `unlist`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also tried this option and, although is a bit more complicated than docendo answer, it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnandaMahto, you mean for the `inter` data.frame ? it's so I can later split the data.frame according to former columns (as it is a matrix, I loose the names when using `as.vector`)

Comment: @CathG, No. I mean in your results. Where did "91781", "91782" and so on come from when the original rownames were "160", "301" and so on.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, there are coming from the call to `cbind` and correspond to the `row.names` of the first element of the `list` I get from the call to `split`. And to be honest, I wouldn't have guessed what the row.names would be. But I can change them afterwards to keep the former names

Comment: It didn't work for me: `Error in data.frame(t(sapply(as.vector(yourmat), function(x) { : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length`

Comment: @MaratTalipov, it's probably because your passing the code with a `data.frame`, not a `matrix`. In this case, you have to use `unlist` instead of `as.vector` in the first line.

Comment: No, I used a `matrix`: `m <- matrix('A_B',nrow=3,ncol=6)`.

Comment: @MaratTalipov, your example `matrix` have neither `colnames` nor `rownames` (unlike the OP's one), that's the reason you're getting the error

Answer (score 2):

base R solution without using data frames:

```
# split
z <- unlist(strsplit(m,'_'))
M <- matrix(c(z[c(T,F)],z[c(F,T)]),nrow=nrow(m))

# properly order columns
i <- 1:ncol(M)
M <- M[,order(c(i[c(T,F)],i[c(F,T)]))]

# set dimnames
rownames(M) <- rownames(m)
colnames(M) <- rep(colnames(m),each=2)

#    9178  9178  3574  3574  3547  3547
# 160 "B"   "B"   "A"   "B"   "B"   "A"  
# 301 "B"   "A"   "A"   "B"   "B"   "B"  
# 303 "B"   "B"   "A"   "B"   "B"   "A"  
# 311 "A"   "A"   "A"   "B"   "B"   "A"  
# 312 "B"   "A"   "A"   "B"   "B"   "A"  
# 314 "B"   "A"   "A"   "B"   "B"   "A"
```

**[Update]**
Here is a small benchmarking study of the proposed solutions (I didn't include the `cSplit` solution because it was too slow):

**Setup:**

```
m <- matrix('A_B',nrow=1000,ncol=2830)
d <- as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

##### 
f.mtrx <- function(m) {
  z <- unlist(strsplit(m,'_'))
  M <- matrix(c(z[c(T,F)],z[c(F,T)]),nrow=nrow(m))

  # properly order columns
  i <- 1:ncol(M)
  M <- M[,order(c(i[c(T,F)],i[c(F,T)]))]

  # set dimnames
  rownames(M) <- rownames(m)
  colnames(M) <- rep(colnames(m),each=2)
  M
}

library(stringi)
f.mtrx2 <- function(m) {
  z <- unlist(stri_split_fixed(m,'_'))
  M <- matrix(c(z[c(T,F)],z[c(F,T)]),nrow=nrow(m))

  # properly order columns
  i <- 1:ncol(M)
  M <- M[,order(c(i[c(T,F)],i[c(F,T)]))]

  # set dimnames
  rownames(M) <- rownames(m)
  colnames(M) <- rep(colnames(m),each=2)
  M
}

#####
library(splitstackshape)
f.cSplit <- function(mydf) cSplit(as.data.table(mydf, keep.rownames = TRUE), names(mydf), "_")

#####
library(stringi)
f.stringi <- function(mydf) `dimnames<-`(do.call(cbind, 
                     lapply(mydf, stri_split_fixed, "_", simplify = TRUE)), 
             list(rownames(mydf), rep(colnames(mydf), each = 2)))

#####
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

f.dplyr <- function(df) lapply(names(df), function(x) separate_(df[x], x, paste0(x,"_",1:2), sep = "_" )) %>% 
  bind_cols

#####
library(iotools)
f.mstrsplit <- function(mydf) `dimnames<-`(do.call(cbind, 
                     lapply(mydf, mstrsplit, "_", ncol = 2, type = "character")),
             list(rownames(mydf), rep(colnames(mydf), each = 2)))



#####
library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(f.mtrx(m), f.mtrx2(m), f.dplyr(d), f.stringi(d), f.mstrsplit(d), replications = 10)
```

**Results:**

```
      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3     f.dplyr(d)           10  27.722   10.162    27.360    0.269          0         0
5 f.mstrsplit(d)           10   2.728    1.000     2.607    0.098          0         0
1      f.mtrx(m)           10  37.943   13.909    34.885    0.799          0         0
2     f.mtrx2(m)           10  15.176    5.563    13.936    0.802          0         0
4   f.stringi(d)           10   8.107    2.972     7.815    0.247          0         0
```

In the updated benchmark, the winner is `f.mstrsplit`.

Comment: It seems to me that the `f.stringi` is the fastest  so it is not clear how the data.table method win here.

Comment: If you really want a winner, check out the update at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, OP mentioned matrix of 1000x2830 size, so I guess performance is crucial here. Your latest solution, `f.mstrsplit()`, is a winner on large matrices.